# Techniques for wrapping code to avoid duplication?

Tags: c++, macros

I have this C++ code that I use in my test cases to force exceptions and increase coverage:

```
    bool exceptionThrown(false);

     try {

         /* One or multiple lines of code */

     } catch (std::runtime_error& e) {
         std::cerr << "    Exception caught: " << e.what() << "\n";
         exceptionThrown = true;
     }

     if (exceptionThrown) {
         std::cerr << "    OK: Exception has been thrown\n";
     } else {
         std::cerr << "    FATAL: Exception should have been thrown\n";
         return(1);
     }
```

As you can imagine, as the number of tests increase this piece of code duplicates a lot, which I do not like at all. I have been thinking on a way to wrap this code with an e.g. macro, but I am not sure if this is a good practice. Do you have any recommendation to avoid code duplication in this case?

Comment: So, why not make a function, storing the common code (the one that you pasted)?

Comment: Why not pass a function pointer to that function that contains the code that should be executed in the `One or multiple lines of code` section? Then you only call this function with a pointer to the production code and thus have no duplicated code...

Comment: Well, What I would do is: wrap the common in a function that takes std::function argument (with no parameters and no return value), and call that common function by passing in a lambda expression which would contain `One or multiple lines of code`.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a test framework such as [googletest](https://github.com/google/googletest) where all these problems are handled nicely?

Answer (score 2):

aside from the obvious questions like "Why not use google test?" and "Why not use boost test framework?" etc.

Here's a way to do what you want:
(edit: updated to reduce typing in the test body - this version is single-threaded, a trivial modification can make it thread-safe)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>

namespace detail {
    struct try_base {
        virtual ~try_base() = default;
        virtual const std::string& message() const = 0;

        static std::unique_ptr<try_base>& last() {
            struct empty : try_base {
                const std::string& message() const override { return _message; }
                std::string _message = "no exception";
            };
            static std::unique_ptr<try_base> _p = std::make_unique<empty>();
            return _p;
        }

        bool threw() const { return _threw; }
        operator bool() const { return !threw(); }
        bool operator!() const { return threw(); }

        bool _threw = false;
    };

    template<class F, class...Args>
    struct try_exec
    : try_base {
        try_exec(F&& f, Args&&...args)
        {
            try {
                f(std::forward<Args>(args)...);
            }
            catch(const std::exception& e) {
                _threw = true;
                _message = e.what();
            }
        }

        const std::string& message() const override { return _message; }

        std::string _message;

    };
}

template<class F, class...Args>
const auto& try_exec(F&& f, Args&&... args)
{
    auto& last = detail::try_base::last();
    last = std::make_unique<detail::try_exec<F, Args...>>(std::forward<F>(f),
                                                          std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    return *last;
}

bool report()
{
    std::cout << detail::try_base::last()->message() << std::endl;
    return true;
}

void example2(int x, int y)
{
    using namespace std;
    if (x < 6) {
        throw std::logic_error("example 2 throws with "s + to_string(x) + " and " + to_string(y));
    }
}

auto main() -> int
{
    try_exec([] {
        throw std::runtime_error("foo");
    }) or report();

    try_exec(&example2, 5, 4) or report();

    try_exec([]{
        example2(5, 4);
    }) or report();



    return 0;
}
```

expected output;

```
test 1 threw: foo
test 2 threw: example 2 throws with 5 and 4
test 3 threw: example 2 throws with 5 and 4
```